# How can I create a Java List/Map/Collection in which I can modify the values but not add nor remove elements from it?

Tags: java, list

I want to create some sort of list where I can modify the values of the objects inside but not be able to add to it nor remove from it once it is initialized. Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: The term you're looking for is "immutable list of mutable items".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the types of objects stored in a `List` (or any `Collection`) are mutable, then the first part of your question is inherent to how Java collections and object references work. Just because an object is contained in a collection doesn't put any restrictions on what I can do with (or _to) that object.

Having said that, if the objects in the list are not mutable (eg, [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html), [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html), or some other value object), there’s nothing you can do to modify them.

## Unmodifiable list

As for the second part, you want an *unmodifiable* collection, and for that you can simply create one using `java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList(List<? extends T>)`. Or in Java 9+, use `List.of` or `List.copyOf` to make an [unmodifiable list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable).

## Fixed size list

If what you want is a `List` that can not be added to or removed from, but *can* have individual elements *replaced*, then consider third-party libraries:

- [`org.apache.commons.collections4.list.FixedSizeList<E>`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.4/org/apache/commons/collections4/list/FixedSizeList.html) from the [*Apache Commons Collections*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/).
- [`org.eclipse.collections.api.list.FixedSizeList`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/11.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/list/FixedSizeList.html) in [*Eclipse Collections*](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/).

Comment: unmodifiableList is not really immutable. That's why it's deliberately not called immutableList. For a truly immutable list, you could use e.g. Guava

Comment: @Michael, clarify the difference, the way you see it.

Comment: Unmodifiable list is a decorator around another list which prevents mutation operations by throwing exceptions when they're called. It can appear to change its contents over time, if something mutates the list which it's decorating. If used in a certain way (i.e. discard the reference to the decorated list) then does become *effectively* immutable.

Answer (score 0):

implement some Collection interface, create variable of Collection implementation, and override add, remove and get methods.
For example:

```
class myCollection implements List{
private List<Integer> list =new ArrayList<>(); 

public  myCollection (Collection col){
list.addAll(col);
}
@Override
Integer get(int i){
return list.get(i);
}
@Override
void remove(int i){
//empty so you cant remove anything
}
}
```

hope you got an idea

Comment: Right, so then if I wanted to call that list, I'd initialize this class and do as I do, right?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).